# JS: Iniciar conexión con la API de YouTube

Tags: javascript, google-api, youtube-api

Estoy intentando conectarme a la API de YouTube desde mi página web para que los usuarios puedan crear y eliminar listas de reproducción.

He elegido Javascript para realizar la comunicación -la web está hecha en PHP, pero comparando el código me pareció más sencillo el ejemplo en JS y además en mi web la creación de la lista de canciones que luego espero transformar en una lista de YouTube se hace mediante un script jQuery-, así que hago uso de la siguiente biblioteca:

https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client

En el `head` de mi web, incluyo el siguiente `script`:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
```

Y luego una llamada a un archivo propio:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../recursos/js/iniciar_api_youtube.js"></script>
```

Con el siguiente código, extraído -y ligeramente modificado- del repositorio de GitHub:

https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/blob/master/docs/start.md

```
gapi.load('client', start); //Carga la biblioteca cliente de JS

function start() 
{
  gapi.client.init( //Inicia la biblioteca cliente de JS
  {
    'apiKey': 'mi_clave_api',
    'clientId': 'mi_client_id', //clientId y scope son opcionales si no se requiere auth 
    'scope': 'profile',
  }).then(
  function() //Inicia y ejecuta la petición API
  {
    return gapi.client.request({'path': 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3',})
  }).then(
  function(response) 
  {
    console.log(response);
    console.log(response.result);
  }, 
  function(reason)
  {
    console.log(reason); 
    console.log('Error: ' + reason.result.error.message);
  });
};
```

No tengo muy claro si el `path` es el correcto, la verdad.

En la consola del navegador se lee lo siguiente, que corresponde a `console.log(reason);`:

```
{result: false, body: "<!DOCTYPE html>↵<html lang=en>↵  <meta charset=utf… on this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>↵", headers: {…}, status: 404, statusText: null}
body: "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=en>\n  <meta charset=utf-8>\n  <meta name=viewport content=\"initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width\">\n  <title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>\n  <style>\n    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}\n  </style>\n  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>\n  <p><b>404.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>\n  <p>The requested URL <code>/youtube/v3</code> was not found on this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>\n"
headers: {content-length: "1571", content-type: "text/html; charset=UTF-8", date: "Sat, 01 May 2021 18:45:48 GMT"}
result: false
status: 404
statusText: null
__proto__: Object
```

Esos `result: false` y `status: 404` supongo que quieren decir que no se está realizando la conexión, así que a ver si me podéis orientar al respecto de qué hacer.

**EDICIÓN**:

Sí, veo que hay un mensaje más detallado al final del HTML que devuelve:

```
<p><b>404.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>\n  <p>The requested URL <code>/youtube/v3</code> was not found on this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>\n
```

Comment: Hola @Javier Blanco!! ¿Has probado con esto: [JavaScript API de Youtube](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript#authorizing_requests)? Puedes cambiar el idioma en la parte de arriba a la derecha. Sobre todo con la línea donde dice: `gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function() {
    handleAPILoaded();
  });`

Comment: ¿Tendría que sustituir mi código por este otro? Es decir, parecen bastante diferentes; ¿hay varias formas de realizar la autenticación? Lo digo porque el código que estoy usando está sacado también de "fuentes oficiales". Tampoco tengo muy claro si necesito usar OAuth, y quizá con la clave de la API sea suficiente.

Comment: Sí, si podrías hacerlo, tendrías que sustituir tu código por ese otro, si. En cuanto a lo que comentas de OAuth, en teoría, con la clave de la API te es suficiente sin problema. Te miro estos días a ver si consigo encontrar algo más si ves que igual te es complicado sustituir tu código, intento mirar a ver que tendrías que añadir / corregir. Saludos!!!

Comment: He encontrado algo que quizás te sirva como respuesta, dime que tal y si eso lo reviso, @Javier Blanco. Saludos!! ;D

Comment: Voy a probar a utilizar este nuevo código, a ver qué tal. Además trae un ejemplo en HTML que no había visto en la documentación que yo había consultado.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es en el `path`, que añades tan solo que te acceda a el API de YouTube, pero no le dices la acción que tendría que realizar en la API tras la ruta. Te pongo un ejemplo: Esta URL de api: `https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people` es incorrecta, pues falta indicarle la acción al final `https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me`, que en este caso es `me`.

Por tanto, en tu código tendrías que añadir en tu código la acción que realizará la API tras la ruta que has puesto. Según lo que explicas en la descripción de arriba, me imagino que lo que a ti te vendrá bien será, o bien el recurso `playlist` o `playlistItems`. Te dejo el enlace de la ayuda para la APId e YouTube que seguro te es de utilidad: [Ayuda para API de YouTube](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/?apix=true). En ese caso, tu ruta debería presentar la siguiente estructura `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/[recurso]`. Por ponerte un ejemplo, tendría que quedarte la línea donde defines el `path`, así:

```
return gapi.client.request({'path': 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems',})
```

O así:

```
return gapi.client.request({'path': 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlist',})
```

Así queda utilizando los dos recursos que te menciono: `playlist` o `playlistItems`, pero sigue la misma estructura para cualquier otro que necesites. Si ves que en tu caso encaja otro recurso, puedes cambiarlo.

Comment: Con los ejemplos de código del enlace que me has pasado he conseguido acceder a mi canal de YouTube y crear una lista de reproducción, así que voy a prescindir del fragmento que estaba intentando usar. Te doy igualmente la recompensa, muchas gracias por tu ayuda.